# how to disable cofirm form resubmission

Tags: php, forms

Hi all I have a search form which is using the post method and it is redirecting the results into a div on a another page but when I refresh the page I get this confirm form resubmission dialog box and I was just wondering to know how can I disable this thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I always use a `header('location:http://url'); exit();` after a page use a POST. If you refresh it will not re-execute or ask for form resubmission. But you need to pass data to the next page, like with sessions.

Comment: would you please tell me how for session use because when I put the header(Location) thing on top of the search result page, it gives header already sent error and also how would I pass data to the next page I am really confused on that part please explain.

Comment: @RaminRahimi — If it was at the top, then you wouldn't get that error. You have something outputting content before that line of code.